# iAd is working on test app, but not when its on appstore

Tags: ios7, app-store, iad

I've just made an app containing iAd in iOS 7.

It's working fine on the development state, testing on the phone.

But after it's been released at the appstore, no ad's are being showed.

*I HAVE checked the code, and the iAd is enabled*

Anyone know why ?

Comment: the iAd banner is being filled up with _real_ adverts in the published version. if there is no advert which the application can hold and show becase the target is different (e.g. age rate, content), no iAd will be posted to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes up to 3 days for the ads to be displayed in a new app.